# Swagger: Select model fields in API response

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a swagger USER object with few fields, e.g.:
id
name
address

I would like to use the same model for two operations:
1. POST - the client will send a list of users *without their ids*. e.g.:

```
[{
   "name": "name1",
   "address": "some address1"
 }, 
 { 
   "name": "name2",
   "address": "some address2"
 }]
```

2. GET - the get request will return only the user Ids:

[
  { 
   "id":    1
  },
  { 
   "id":    2
  }
]

Is there a way to reuse the same "USER" model for both operations? i.e. to make some kind of fields selection? Or should I create a separate schema for each one of them, one schema for the IDs (GET) and another for the POST?